# Android: Get the TextView in onItemClickListener() of ListView

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

I am developing a SoundBoard application. My class extends ListActivity and the listview is as follows

```
[Image] [Text]
[Image] [Text]
[Image] [Text]
```

Now when the user clicks on any textview, I need to change the image of that textview. I implement that by the following code.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
           int position, long id) {

TextView tv1 = (TextView) view;
//Here I change the image with tv1 as reference
}
```

But I need an **alternate way to get the selected TextView** . Because when I change the image using the above method,  if user selects third row in the list, the image changes in the third row of the second scroll page, the third row of the third scroll page and so on gets affected.Not only the required textview image changes, but one textview in upcoming scroll pages are changed when list is scrolled. Hope you get my problem. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the behavior that you're seeing comes from the fact that Android recycles the TextViews used in the ListView; that's why `Adapter.getView()` has a [convertView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) argument. (Once a TextView has scrolled off the screen, it can be passed into `Adapter.getView()` via the `convertView` argument, to be re-used for an item that's been scrolled onto the display.)

You might try adding a [android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) to the ListView, to track which items in the list are on screen at a given time. You probably also need to override `Adapter.getView()` to force the image back to the default (or more generally, to use whichever image is appropriate for the newly displayed item.)

Comment: Can u help me with the code please. Because I am a newbie. And it sounds complex to me. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I don't think it should be hard to write, but I wouldn't know your code well enough to know where to start. Give it your best shot, and if you're having problems, then post the code here (or in another question.)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tested my self you may try for by adding onClck attribute in Textview
`<android :onclick="name of function>`

Cheers,
Kariyachan

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This sounds to be a good idea. But how do i get the reference to the textview in the function. Should the function include parameters.

Comment: yes .for example myfunction(View v) then u can get id of Textview clicked by fn getId() do your stuff cheers,Kariyachan

Comment: Can you please help me with the code. So that I will get a better idea. Thanks.

Comment: I tried that. But it did not work form. I am not sure If I was right in implementing your idea.